# Travis CI, unable to run tests - Error: activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2

Tags: ruby, cocoapods, travis-ci, activesupport, kiwi

I have an open sourced `Obj-C` [repository](https://github.com/EvgenyKarkan/EKAlgorithms) with `Kiwi` unit testing framework as `CocoaPods` dependency.
To run tests I'm using `Travis CI` continious integration tool.

Everything was fine previously, all unit tests were executed, but now I'm getting Travis CI build error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
    activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2.
```

[image]

Here is my `.travis.yml` file:

```
language: objective-c

before_install:
- sw_vers
- cd EKAlgorithmsApp

install: make install

script: make ci
```

And here is my `Makefile`:

```
install:
    gem install cocoapods --no-ri --no-rdoc
    gem install xcpretty  --no-ri --no-rdoc
    pod install

ci:
    xcodebuild -workspace EKAlgorithmsApp.xcworkspace/ -scheme EKAlgorithmsSpecs -sdk macosx -configuration Release clean test | xcpretty -c
```

It seems that something in configurations has changed on Travis CI side, but I'm not very familiar with Ruby, so I need a help of how to fix that warning to run my tests successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by adding next line to my `.travis.yml` file:

```
osx_image: xcode7.3
```

So my `.yml` file now looks like:

```
language: objective-c
osx_image: xcode7.3

before_install:
- sw_vers
- cd EKAlgorithmsApp

install: make install

script: make ci
```